Why do i get "property 'push' does not exits on type 'string|string[]'
I am using vs code editor for development. I was learning typescript array methods and this is the code:
const users = ["Mani", "John", "Max", ["A", "B", "C"]];

const shallowCopy = [...users];
console.log(shallowCopy, "** show copy");
console.log(users[3], "** users[3]");
users[3].push("D");        // Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
console.log(users[3], "** users[3] after push");
users[3].push(["E", "F"]); // Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.

I am not know why i get this error. I checked the documentation on both typescript and javascript and it appears that code on push is valid. The target for compiler option is es2016.
I tried checking the documentation and they state the code is valid. The odd part is when i disabled the vscode builtin extension for Typescript the problem seems to go away.

Paste the relevant part of the code, not an image.

It is simply because there can be two types as far as it knows, and it will warn you that it's not guaranteed to be an array (it could be.a string!) - if you want to define that item 3 is an array, you need to manually tell it about the structure of your array with @type {[ string, string, string, string[]]} as the type of your shallowCopy array.

Are you really trying to push ["E", "F"]? So that it eventually becomes ["A", "B", "C", "D", ["E", "F"]]? Or is that a typo and you really mean to write push("E", "F") (without the brackets)?

Inferred type of users is (string | string[])[]
This means that each element can be either:

a string
an array of strings

You know that users[3] happens to be a string[], which is why pushing a new element to it is legal.
On the other hand the same operation on users[2] is illegal.
You can make an extra check to ensure that element you are accessing is an array. TS will leverage this check to narrow down the type
const users = ["Mani", "John", "Max", ["A", "B", "C"]];
if (Array.isArray(users[3])) {
    // TS narrowed down the type of users[3] to string[]
    users[3].push("D");
}

An alternative could be an explicit record type for users:
const users: [string, string, string, string[]] = ["Mani", "John", "Max", ["A", "B", "C"]];
users[3].push("D");

This forces types of elements at each index, and makes your operation valid (but prevents you from changing types at each index)

I'd be inclined to write something like const users = ["Mani", "John", "Max", ["A", "B", "C"] satisfies string[]] as const; to get the relevant type without having to spell out the other parts of the array type with an explicit annotation.  Also, note that they are pushing ["E", "F"] which doesn't work with your code, but I can't tell if that's a typo or they really want some recursive nested type X = (string | X)[] thing.
